# Slick with Play: db update from outside a Controller DBAction

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, actor, slick

I have a Play application in which I am handling the database communication using Slick.

Everything works smoothly so far, but I have the following problem: I have an Akka actor that communicates with remote systems, gets data from these systems and has to update the database using these data.

Now, I have some methods in the model that update the db, but they expect an implicit Session parameter: if the call to these methods comes from the Controller actions, since they are DBActions, they automatically handle the session, but if I want to invoke these methods from outside the Controller (i.e., from those actors), should I create my own session (using Database.fromURL)? Could it interfere with the one automatically created and handled by the Controller?

Comment: If you don't call the method from the controller you could simply use `DB.withSession { implicit s: Session => { /* some computation */ } }`, this should make it up for the missing `DBAction`, as for the Slick documentation (which I cannot find at the moment) this session will be closed automatically.

Comment: Found it [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/connection.html#session-handling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got curious and did some digging, the `DBAction` class extends the `CurrentDBAction` trait which has an apply method:

```
def apply[A](dbName: String, bodyParser: BodyParser[A] = anyContent)(requestHandler: DBSessionRequest[A] => SimpleResult)(implicit app: Application = null) = {
  val current = db(dbName, Option(app))
  applyForDB(current)(requestHandler)(bodyParser)(current.withSession)(errorPage)
}
```

Basically what it's doing is create a `DB` object and passing it to the `applyForDB` function together with `withSession` which should (should because I'm not an expert and the source code is not that easy to read) be exactly the same as doing this

```
DB.withSession {
  implicit session: Session => {
    /* some computation */
  }
}
```

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/blob/master/code/src/main/scala/play/api/db/slick/DBAction.scala).